# C# Split string by tag and create an iterable data structure

Tags: c#

I have this string:

```
<item>
  <node1>Name</node1>
    <childNode1>Nickname</childNode1>
  <node2>Surname</node2>
</item>
<item>
  <node1>AnotherName</node1>
  <node2>AnotherSurname</node2>
</item>
```

I want to split this string by "item", and create a data structure from text extracted from all nodes, for example:
{"Name","Nickname", "Surname"}

{"Name", "Surname"}

Comment: Cool idea, what did you try so far?

Comment: BTW: you cannot (never) extract nodes from a string. You need to have a valid XML for working with nodes, and currently your string does not match a valid XML.

Comment: That is the problem - this is not, and never won't be - a valid xml, or html.

Comment: What I've tried - I can extract text from nodes with:
MatchCollection names = Regex.Matches(mystring, @"<node1(.*?)>(.*?)</node1>" and it works. When I do the same with "item" - it returns nothing

Comment: Will there always be a `node` AND a `node2` or are they optional?

Comment: they are optional

Comment: Just to be more clear - my idea is to split this string by item, so I can add this to a list or some other data structure, and then iterate by this item to extract values from nodes.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to be xml, but the childnode1 is not correct for how xml works.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: 'childNode1' is just a (another) child of the node 'item', the formatting is just a bit.... suggestive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install HtmlAgilityPack you can solve your task easily:

```
public class Item
{
    public List<string> Properties { get; set; }

    public static List<Item> LoadItems(string text)
    {
        var items = new List<Item>();
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(text);

        var docItems = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//item");
        foreach (var docItem in docItems)
        {
            var list = docItem.ChildNodes
                .Where(n => n.NodeType != HtmlNodeType.Text)
                .Select(n => n.InnerText)
                .ToList();
            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                items.Add(new Item { Properties = list });
            }
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

This class has a list of properties ("Name,Nickname,Surname" for your first item) and a LoadItems that parse your text. Simply select all "item" nodes and iterate the returned list selecting the InnerText (the content of each node).

You can test your sample:

```
const string text = @"<item>
  <node1>Name</node1>
    <childNode1>Nickname</childNode1>
  <node2>Surname</node2>
</item>
<item>
  <node1>AnotherName</node1>
  <node2>AnotherSurname</node2>
</item>";

var allItems = Item.LoadItems(text);
```

Comment: I'll test it tomorrow, I thought html agility pack works only with valid html file, I've tried it, but I guess I gave up too soon. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: My code is working, I've tested. In fact, HtmlAgilityPack is very flexible because HTML usually is not well formed. This library works with unclosed tag, for example.

Answer (score 0):

While adding a root element, in order to create an XML might be better

Another way might be to use this regexp: https://regex101.com/r/eKMjeu/1

The code from the generator (on that side) gives:

```
string pattern = @"<(\/?node[0-9]|\/?childNode[0-9])>*>|\n";
        string substitution = ",";
        string input = @"<item>
  <node1>Name</node1>
    <childNode1>Nickname</childNode1>
  <node2>Surname</node2>
</item>
<item>
  <node1>AnotherName</node1>
  <node2>AnotherSurname</node2>
</item>";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
```

The results in `result` are:

```
<item>
,  ,Name,
,    ,Nickname,
,  ,Surname,
,</item>
,<item>
,  ,AnotherName,
,  ,AnotherSurname,
,</item>
```

Which might make life a little bit easier

You could add:

```
result = result.Replace('\r',' ');
result = result.Replace(@"</item>",Environment.NewLine.ToString());
result = "," + result.Replace(@"<item>","");
```

Which leave you with:

```
, ,  ,Name, ,    ,Nickname, ,  ,Surname, , 
 , ,  ,AnotherName, ,  ,AnotherSurname, ,
```

All in all, pretty messy...

The other solution using XML, seems much nicer:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

string str = @"<item>
  <node1>Name</node1>
    <childNode1>Nickname</childNode1>
  <node2>Surname</node2>
</item>
<item>
  <node1>AnotherName</node1>
  <node2>AnotherSurname</node2>
</item>";

str = "<root>" + str + "</root>";

XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(str);

foreach(XElement e in xml.Descendants("node1")) {
    XElement node2 = e.XPathSelectElement("../node2");
    System.Console.WriteLine("{\"" + e.Value + "\",\"" + node2.Value + "\"}");
}
```

output:

```
{"Name","Surname"}
{"AnotherName","AnotherSurname"}
```

Of course this second solutions (currently) lacks error checking, and should have started with `xml.Descendants("item")`, but ...

Comment: Wow thank you very much ! It surely give me some ideas to work on! Appreciate that!